# Channels with interface type and pointers to structs as concrete types

Tags: go, interface, channel

I'm attempting to generalize some of my code and I thought I might be able to pull some common code together, but I'm hitting my head against a type-system problem.

Let's assume I have an interface like this:

```
type Hashable interface {
    GetHash() []byte
}
```

and I have a couple of concrete types like this:

```
type Transaction struct {
    Hash                 []byte    `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=hash,proto3" json:"hash,omitempty"`
}

func (m *Transaction) GetHash() []byte {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Hash
    }
    return nil
}
```

Notice that these are generated by `protoc`, and I can probably not change them easily. While the type itself does not implement `Hashable`, the pointer to the struct should if I'm not mistaken.

The issue arises when I create a function that accepts a channel of type `chan Hashable` and try to pass in a `chan *Transaction`, like this:

```
func consume(c chan Hashable) {
    // Do something with the elements from c
}

func main() {
    var c2 chan *Transaction
    consume(c2)
}
```

(I created a small example to show this issue in the [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/I2C-Zkkam0W))

I could of course create a new struct that repacks the fields that `consume` needs, but that seems like a much worse option.

Is there a clean solution for this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t just create `c2` as a `chan *Hashable`?

Comment: @MTCoster OP would likely want `chan Hashable` instead. You don't often need to use pointers to interfaces.

Comment: Good question, I was planning to reuse the `chan *Transaction` in another context as well, where I actually need the elements to be `*Transaction`. I can create a function that just converts by reading one channel and writing to the other, but that seems kind of wasteful (context switches, an extra gorouting, etc).

Comment: If you follow Gavin’s advice and drop the pointer, you use either and cast in the other case.

Comment: Notice that `chan Hashable` has no pointer, and that's exactly the case I'm trying to get working :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: `chan *Transaction` is not an interface - it's a specific type. So it cannot implement interface or `chan Hashable` by it's nature. You need to use specific channel.

You can convert `Transaction` values to `Hashable` on the fly with a grouting like this:

```
func convertor(ct chan *Transaction) chan Hashable {
    ch := make(chan Hashable)
    go func() {
        for t := range(ct) {
            ch <- Hashable(t)
        }

    }()
    return ch
}
```

and call

```
consume(convertor(c2))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pd2EfhCehYz